# Using Default ThreadPool SynchronisationContext in ASP.NET

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, asynchronous

Reading these two articles, [SynchronisationContext](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/gg598924.aspx) and [Async/Await](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/jj991977.aspx). I'm very familiar with the way the ASP.NET SynchronisationContext handles the re-entry of async method execution back onto the request thread.

One of the big issues with re-entry is that if you use `.Wait()` or `.Result` you can cause a deadlock, why:

> When the await completes, it attempts to execute the remainder of the async method within the captured context. But that context already has a thread in it, which is (synchronously) waiting for the async method to complete.

You get this because of the single thread that is being used by the SynchronisationContext and the way it `permits only one chunk of code to run at a time.`

What would be the implications of using `Task.Factory.StartNew` and assigning it a `ThreadPool` `SynchronisationContext` within an ASP.NET application?

I'm not bothered by why you would do this, rather more what would happen?

I know you are never supposed to Fire-and-Forget an async operation in ASP.NET because the thread may be cleared up before the async operation has completed. Would this also be true in the case of a `ThreadPool` `SynchronisationContext`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> What would be the implications of using Task.Factory.StartNew and assigning it a ThreadPool SynchronisationContext within an ASP.NET application?

There's no reason to use `StartNew`; `Task.Run` is superior in almost every use case. Also, you don't need to "assign" a thread pool `SynchronizationContext`, because thread pool threads have that naturally.

So, sure, you *could* do this:

```
await Task.Run(async () => { ... });
```

and all of your `...` code will run on a thread pool thread (outside the request context), and resume on a thread pool thread (outside the request context).

This usage also doesn't have the problem of fire-and-forget, because our code is `await`ing the result.

But I generally discourage this on ASP.NET, because think about what it's doing:

- The code queues work (`...`) to the thread pool.
- Then it asynchronously waits for that work to complete. During this time, the original request thread is returned to the thread pool.
- When the work completes, the calling method continues in the request context.

So it causes an extra thread switch while giving you no benefit. It's *possible* to have a small amount of parallelism, but then you're talking about some potentially serious scalability limitations. Every time I've done parallelism on ASP.NET in production, I've ended up ripping it out.

> I know you are never supposed to Fire-and-Forget an async operation in ASP.NET because the thread may be cleared up before the async operation has completed. Would this also be true in the case of a ThreadPool SynchronisationContext.

Actually, it's not because of a particular thread getting aborted. It's because the entire AppDomain is torn down. This includes aborting *all* threads.

So, yes, on ASP.NET, fire-and-forget using the thread pool is just as bad as any other kind of fire-and-forget:

```
Task.Run(() => ...); // bad!
```

At the very least, you should register the work with the ASP.NET runtime (which does **not** make the work reliable in the true sense of the word - it only *minimizes* the chance that the work will be aborted). Modern ASP.NET has [`HostingEnvironment.QueueBackgroundWorkItem`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.hosting.hostingenvironment.queuebackgroundworkitem(v=vs.110).aspx) for this.

Before ASP.NET added this method, I had a library that registered the work in a very similar way. I [used `Task.Run`](https://github.com/StephenCleary/AspNetBackgroundTasks/blob/master/src/AspNetBackgroundTasks/Internal/RegisteredTasks.cs#L81) on purpose to run the registered work outside any request context and with a thread pool `SynchronizationContext`.

Comment: So what would the effect of calling `.Result` and `.Wait()` on a `Task.Run` still be the same because the synchronisation context to execute the rest of the work is still executing one at a time because it is the ASP.NET context

Comment: I thought that the `Task.Run` would use the a captured context, but I can see from the [source code](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/threading/Tasks/Task.cs,89fc01f3bb88eed9) which is [ThreadPoolTaskScheduler](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/threading/Tasks/TaskScheduler.cs,495c69a13f3b023f)

Comment: @CallumLinington: If you block on the task returned from `Task.Run`, then you'd be blocking a thread in the request context. And you'd be using up two threads while that work was in progress instead of one.

Comment: So the problem only gets worse!